# How to output the class tag when the component has a wicket:id?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm a Wicket newbie. I wonder if someone could help me with the following:
I have:

```
.centredtab{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

and:

```
 <form class="centredtab"wicket:id="questionform">
```

but the class `centredtab` for the form is not being rendered. Is there a method in the Wicket API to ensure that this class attribute will be rendered in order that the form is centred?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket simple attribute appender to rescue you see here http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html

Essentially,

```
  myForm.add(new AttributeAppender("class", 
             new Model<String>("centredtab"), " "));
```

---

alright. I think you're missing the parameter `addAttributeIfNotPresent` (refer the doc above)

Try this

```
   myForm.add(new AttributeAppender("class", true, 
                                     new Model<String>("centredtab"), " "));
```

As quoted

> ```
> AttributeAppender(String attribute, boolean addAttributeIfNotPresent, 
>                                 IModel<?> appendModel, String separator)
> ```
>
> Creates an AttributeModifier that appends the appendModel's value to the current value of the attribute, and will add the attribute when addAttributeIfNotPresent is true.

should solve your issue of not creating the attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason: form.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("centredtab"), " ")); dies not work. Bear in mind my html is the same as above except I've now deleted the class="centredtab"bit-<form wicket:id="questionform">

Comment: Yeah that's alright that you've removed the class. You do not see `<form class="centredtab" wicket:id="questionform">` when you view source in your browser? It's less likely. Are you adding this class to correct `form`?

Comment: @Nishant- all I see is this:<form wicket:id="questionform" id="questionform94" method="post" action="?

Comment: Form form = new Form("questionform");
   form.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("centredtab"), " "));
  add(form);

Comment: @Nishant Still alludes me this one-form.add(new AttributeAppender("class", true, new Model<String>("centredtab"), " ")); and:.centredtab{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: @E Shindler well, I am not a good HTML/CSS guy. I can tell you that the method mentioned above works for me -- it adds the class. Now, as far as centering the form issue is, I can suggest you to see this http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread331704.html this is pure styling issue. You may start a new question pasting your HTML code and asking why form is not centered.

Comment: @E Shindler also, try to wrap the `form` in a `div` and set the div's `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Solved-seemed like it was a problem saying: margin-left:auto margin-right:auto on the form. Thank you!!!

Comment: @E Shindler Glad it helped. Now, I wonder. If you don't do it in wicket, instead just keep the class in HTML, it would work as well. I did not realize that your main issue was CSS related not dynamic insertion of class. But you learned a new thing. So, overall it's good.

Comment: @Nishant I also thought it was a Wicket issue. Thank you again!