# Setting attribute to the option of DropDownChoice

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

I have a DropDownChoice:

```
        DropDownChoice dateSpanChoice = new DropDownChoice("dateSpan", new PropertyModel(getModel(), "dateSpan"), dateSpans, new IChoiceRenderer() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 10105L;

            @Override
            public String getIdValue(Object object, int index) {
                return ((DateSpan) object).getId() + "";
            }

            @Override
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object object) {
                DateTime today = new DateTime();
                DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(today.getYear(), today.getMonthOfYear(), today.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
                DateSpan dateSpan = (DateSpan) object;
                DateTime fromDate = dateSpan.getFromDate();
                DateTime toDate = dateSpan.getToDate();
                boolean currentDateIsEqualOrAfterFromDate = currentDate.isEqual(fromDate) | currentDate.isAfter(fromDate);
                boolean currentDateIsEqualOrBeforeToDate = currentDate.isEqual(toDate) | currentDate.isBefore(toDate);
                boolean currentDateBelongsToCurrentRange = currentDateIsEqualOrAfterFromDate & currentDateIsEqualOrBeforeToDate;
                if (currentDateBelongsToCurrentRange) {
                    return ((DateSpan) object).getDisplayValue() + " *";
                } else {
                    return ((DateSpan) object).getDisplayValue();
                }
            }
        }) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 10106L;

            protected CharSequence getDefaultChoice(final Object selected) {
                CharSequence charSequence = super.getDefaultChoice(selected);                   
                System.out.println("=============================================================");
                //System.out.println(charSequence);
                //THIS CHARSEQUENCE IS RENRING EMPTY STRING
                if(StringUtils.isBlank(charSequence.toString())) {
                    System.out.println("CHARSEQUENCE IS BLANK");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CHARSEQUENCE IS NOT BLANK");
                }
                return charSequence;
            }
        };
        dateSpanChoice.setNullValid(false);
```

I am trying to add style="background-color: red" to the selected option. So I am overriding getDefaultChoice() but as you can see it is commented in code the CharSequence is empty.

Is there any way to set an attribute to a particular option of DropDownChoice?

Thanks and Regards.

Note: the DateTime is Joda time

Comment: Try to archive what you would like to do in plain static html. As far as i know, this is not possible with a <select> tag. Places i have seen on the internet emulated a <select> look and feel via javascript and <div> and than had the freedom to style the dropdown part to their hearts content.

Comment: Hi Tapas, Have you able to style the options in DropDownChoice itself OR you need to change your component to Select/SelectOption instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need Select/SelectOption instead of DropDownChoice for more complex uses of  element.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the behavior package in Wicket.
 You can use the [AttributeAppender](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html)-class for instance.

Comment: thansk. I know about AttributeAppeneder. How can I add AttributeAppender to the option? I guess it can be added to DropDownChoice, isn't it?

Comment: correct, with the add()-method. found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891639/how-to-output-the-class-tag-when-the-component-has-a-wicketid

Comment: so the AttributeAppender is not the way to achive this!

Comment: Very unhelpful. You are clearly misunderstanding the question. Modifiers/appenders **do** render attributes in generated markup **but** the question is whether Wicket's API provides a way to add such an appender to individual options. Adding an appender to the DropDownChoice would append an attribute to the <select>, not the <option>'s. Unfortunately, the DropDownChoice API does not seem to provide a way of doing so. The alternative is to use Select and SelectOption, which gives you more control of the markup but unfortunately, you lose some basic functionality provided by DropDownChoice.